# What is the difference between TFS and Sharepoint in terms of monitoring a Project's Lifecycle?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Working with a large team, we often use SharePoint and TFS to deploy and store our code, documents etc. However, Why do we use SharePoint in some places and TFS in others. Please explain the criteria and the basic difference between the two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is a document management system that has support for lists.

TFS is an Application Lifecycle Management tool. It provides SCM(Git or TFVC) as well as Work Items (effort management), agile planning tools, test tools, build tools, and release management.